# Is it possbible to disable html5 video controls on switching to fullscreen?

Tags: video, custom-controls, html5-video, fullscreen, addeventlistener

My requirement is to never show the controls. But when i switch to fullscreen the contols are enabled automatically. Is there a way to diable them?

i tried disabling through javascript (video.controls=false) but in vain, whereas the same code works fine in another part of my program.

i have included the controls disabling code inside the webkitfullscreenchange listeners handler. The handler is getting invoked on full screen button click but the controls are not gettin disabled.

P.S am enabling full screen on user button click.

This is my webkitfullscreenchange  listerner code:

```
document.addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', function() {
    video.controls = false;
    console.log('webkitfullscreenchange event fired');      
}, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessig the following should work in css

```
ul.vjs-controls > li.vjs-fullscreen-control { display: none; }
```